# SQL SERVER Check constraint - Querying other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I want to enforce a business rule on my database table to ensure that a row can't be inserted if the table already contains rows meeting a certain criteria.

Was wanting to use a CHECK constraint but suspect this may have to be done via a trigger.

Is there a way to do this via a CHECK constraint? OR is there another way to do this at the database level without using a trigger?

Comment: Please provide an example of **specifically** what you are trying to do. Always best to try and do this declaratively.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the criteria you're testing for?

Comment: I don't want to insert a row if there is an existing row with an id column in a certain range

Comment: Looks like this is possible via a scalar valued function and a check constraint

Comment: @AJM - Performance will be poor and difficult to get correct so it works under all circumstances (concurrency, multi row inserts, snapshot isolation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your specific criteria (which you haven't shared yet), you may be able to do a [unique filtered index.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)

This is normally faster than functions or other workarounds.

General format would be:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_IndexName ON MyTable (FieldstoIndex)
WHERE <filter to only include certain rows>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this will meet my needs. I have a user id and a status id and want to ensure that there can only be one row  for a user with a specific status id e.g.

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_IndexName ON MyTable (UserId,StatusId) WHERE StatusId = X

Comment: @AJM Actually it sounds like you just need to use the unique index and the filter may be superfluous.

Comment: There are other statuses that can have multiple entries though